# File upload using formik and express backend

Tags: express, file-upload, formik

I am trying to upload an image along with a title and some text for a post. I am using Formik form with an onSubmit in the client folder of the project :

```
const [charCount, setCharCount] = useState(0);
  const [fileObject, setFileObject] = useState(null);
  
  const initialValues = {
    title: "",
    postText: "",
    file: null
  };
  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    title: Yup.string().required("Required"),
    postText: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  });

  const onSubmitHandler = (values) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", values.title);
    formData.append("postText", values.postText);
    console.log(fileObject);
    formData.append("file", document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
    console.log(formData);
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:3001/posts/create",
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            accessToken: localStorage.getItem("token"),
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
    
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}
      >
        <Form className="create-post-form">
          <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onChange={(e) => {
            setFileObject(e.target.files[0]);
          }}/>
          <Field id="input-create-post" name="title" placeholder="Post Title" />
          <ErrorMessage name="title" component="span" className="error" />
          <Field
            id="input-create-post-text"
            name="postText"
            placeholder="What's the story?"
            as="textarea"
            onKeyUp={(e) => setCharCount(e.target.value.length)}
            maxLength="250"
          />
          <div className="char-count">
            <span id={charCount===250 ? "char-count-max" : "char-count"}>{charCount}/250</span>
          </div>
          <ErrorMessage name="title" component="span" className="error" />
          <Button type="submit" title="Post" onSubmit={onSubmitHandler} />
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};
```

On the server side (server folder), in the Posts.js route where I am handling the request :

```
router.post("/create",validateToken, async(req,res)=>{
    if(req.files === null){
        return res.status(400).json({message: "No file uploaded"});
    }
    const file = req.files;
    console.log(file);
    res.json(req.body)
})
```

On submitting the form, an empty object {} is logged on the console. And the res.json(req.body) returns the title and postText successfully, but the file is {} (empty). How do I fix this? Please help!

I tried submitting the form with the above code and got this response:
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctoYD.png)

I need the file object to be the actual fileObject that I have as a state.

Comment: use `multer` middleware https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html